# size[policy] of nested QMainWindows

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I've got a `QMainWindow` in a `QTabWidget` in a[n otherwise empty] `QVBoxLayout` in a `QWidget` in a `QTabWidget` in a `QMainWindow`.

But the size of the internal `QMainWindow` is being reported as 640x480 (the size of the external `QMainWindow`) when the `sizeHint` is reported as 70x26 (smaller than the widgets inside the internal `QMainWindow`). It looks like 70x26 to me.

How can I adjust the size to stretch to fill the internal `QTabWidget`/`QVBoxLayout`/`QWidget`?

The internal `QMainWindow` has a `QTextEdit` for the central widget and a `QComboBox` in a `QDockWidget` on the bottom docking area. The external `QTabWidget` has other `QWidget`s which work fine.

Comment: Yes, I did, which I forgot about.  Thanks for asking.  There is a QVBoxLayout in between the two QTabWidgets.  I'm not sure I can remove it with the way this app is architected, but I'll try and see if that fixes it.  Thanks.

Comment: I forgot to set the QVBoxLayout and add the internal QTabWidget.  Thanks for making me look it over again.

Comment: Glad it helped. It's often one of these little things. ;)

Comment: Now if I can get the QTextEdit to fill the central widget area, I'll be in business.

Comment: Designer stuck a QWidget between the QMainWindow and the QTextEdit, and made that the central widget.  The size hint on that QWidget was -1,-1.  Removing it and setting the QTextEdit as the central widget works well.